# web map creation features attribute table with alleged problem

Tags: qgis2web

I created a web map with QGIS2WEB . But when I generate the web map through the OL3 the column name is represented by integers. In the leaflet option , the column name is represented correctly, but the information for each column are represented as undefined.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Can you tell us which version of qgis2web you are using? You can find that out in the plugin manager.

Answer (score 3):

I released qgis2web 1.5.0 earlier today which tries to fix these two problems. Make sure you have that version, and try your exports again.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom Chadwin, updated the plugin and it works perfectly.

Comment: It would be possible to implement the plugin by adding a tool to measure areas? Thank you!